# Как привязать "Menu" к ImageView?

Tags: android, menu, imageview

Вместо стандартных "трёх точек" поставил ImageView. Как привязать "Menu" к ImageView ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вы пробовали просто заменить 3 точки у уже готового меню, с помощью стилей?

```
 <!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonOverflow</item>
</style>

<!-- Style to replace actionbar overflow icon. set item 'android:actionOverflowButtonStyle' in AppTheme -->
<style name="MyActionButtonOverflow" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

Получается меню уже сразу будет "привязано".

Comment: Просто поменять картинку можно было бы, но у меня меню перенесено на другую сторону, в нестандартное место